Universal quantifier introduction rule in Lean 4
In the previous question I made a small mistake in the theorem statement (incorrect brackets). I added the Inhabited hypothesis and proved it on paper. But I don't know, how to use the universal quantifier introduction rule from Logics to create an object Hforall : (∀ (x : α), P x) from x and Hp?
namespace Block_1
theorem T5 {p q : Prop} : ¬(p → q) ↔ (p ∧ ¬q) := by
  apply Iff.intro
  -- ¬ (p → q) -> (p ∧ ¬q)
  . intro (H : ¬(p → q))
    apply byContradiction
    intro (H1 : ¬(p ∧ ¬q))
    cases (em q) with
    | inl Hq =>
      have Hpq : (p → q) := fun _ => Hq
      exact (H Hpq)
    | inr Hnq =>
      cases (em p) with
      | inl Hp =>
        have Hpnq : (p ∧ ¬q) := And.intro Hp Hnq
        exact (H1 Hpnq)
      | inr Hnp =>
        have H2 : (¬q → ¬p) := fun _ => Hnp
        rewrite [←@contraposition p q] at H2
        exact (H H2)
  -- (p ∧ ¬ q) -> ¬ (p → q)
  . intro (H : p ∧ ¬q)
    have Hp : p := And.left H
    have Hnq : ¬q := And.right H
    apply byContradiction
    intro (H1 : ¬¬ (p → q))
    rewrite [not_not] at H1
    have Hq : q := (H1 Hp)
    exact Hnq Hq
end Block_1

theorem not_exists_forall {α : Type} {P : α -> Prop} :
  ¬ (∃ x, P x) ↔ ∀ x, ¬ P x := by
  apply Iff.intro
  . intro Hneg
    intro x
    intro Hp
    have Hexists : (∃ x, P x) := Exists.intro x Hp
    exact Hneg Hexists
  . intro H1
    intro Hexists
    cases Hexists with
    | intro x Hp =>
      have Hneg : ¬P x := H1 x
      exact Hneg Hp

theorem T6 {α : Type} (Hne : Nonempty α) {P Q : α -> Prop} :
  ((∀ x, P x) → ¬ (∃ y, Q y)) → ∃ x, ∀ y, (Q y → ¬ P x) := by
  intro H
  apply Classical.byContradiction
  intro H1
  rewrite [not_exists_forall] at H1
  have Hexists := Classical.exists_true_of_nonempty Hne
  cases Hexists with
  | intro x _ =>
    specialize H1 x
    rewrite [Classical.not_forall] at H1
    cases H1 with
    | intro x1 H2 =>
      rewrite [Block_1.T5] at H2
      have Hq : Q x1 := And.left H2
      have Hp : ¬ ¬ P x := And.right H2
      rewrite [Classical.not_not] at Hp
      have Hforall : (∀ (x : α), P x) := sorry
      specialize H Hforall
      rewrite [not_exists_forall] at H
      specialize H x1
      exact H Hq

This is the state before Hforall:
α : Type
Hne : Nonempty α
P Q : α → Prop
H : (∀ (x : α), P x) → ¬∃ y, Q y
x : α
h✝ : True
x1 : α
H2 : Q x1 ∧ ¬¬P x
Hq : Q x1
Hp : P x
⊢ False


After a lot of thinking and attempts I proved it. This is the full code that can be type checked with Lean:
namespace Block_1
theorem modus_tollens {P Q : Prop} (h : P → Q) (hn : ¬Q) : ¬P := by
  intro hp
  -- From our assumption, we can derive Q using h
  have hq : Q := h hp
  -- This leads to a contradiction with our assumption that ¬Q is true
  exact hn hq

theorem contraposition {A B : Prop} : (A → B) ↔ (¬B → ¬A) := by
  apply Iff.intro
  -- (A → B) -> (¬B → ¬A)
  . intro (H : A → B) (Hnb : ¬B)
    intro (Ha : A)
    have Hb : B := H Ha
    exact (Hnb Hb)
  . intro (H : ¬B → ¬A) (Ha : A)
    rewrite [←@Classical.not_not A] at Ha
    have HB : ¬¬B := modus_tollens H Ha
    rewrite [Classical.not_not] at HB
    exact HB

theorem T5 {p q : Prop} : ¬(p → q) ↔ (p ∧ ¬q) := by
  apply Iff.intro
  -- ¬ (p → q) -> (p ∧ ¬q)
  . intro (H : ¬(p → q))
    apply Classical.byContradiction
    intro (H1 : ¬(p ∧ ¬q))
    cases (Classical.em q) with
    | inl Hq =>
      have Hpq : (p → q) := fun _ => Hq
      exact (H Hpq)
    | inr Hnq =>
      cases (Classical.em p) with
      | inl Hp =>
        have Hpnq : (p ∧ ¬q) := And.intro Hp Hnq
        exact (H1 Hpnq)
      | inr Hnp =>
        have H2 : (¬q → ¬p) := fun _ => Hnp
        rewrite [←@contraposition p q] at H2
        exact (H H2)
  -- (p ∧ ¬ q) -> ¬ (p → q)
  . intro (H : p ∧ ¬q)
    have Hp : p := And.left H
    have Hnq : ¬q := And.right H
    apply Classical.byContradiction
    intro (H1 : ¬¬ (p → q))
    rewrite [Classical.not_not] at H1
    have Hq : q := (H1 Hp)
    exact Hnq Hq
end Block_1

theorem not_exists_forall {α : Type} {P : α -> Prop} :
  ¬ (∃ x, P x) ↔ ∀ x, ¬ P x := by
  apply Iff.intro
  . intro Hneg
    intro x
    intro Hp
    have Hexists : (∃ x, P x) := Exists.intro x Hp
    exact Hneg Hexists
  . intro H1
    intro Hexists
    cases Hexists with
    | intro x Hp =>
      have Hneg : ¬P x := H1 x
      exact Hneg Hp

theorem T6 {α : Type} (Hne : Nonempty α) {P Q : α -> Prop} :
  ((∀ x, P x) → ¬ (∃ y, Q y)) → ∃ x, ∀ y, (Q y → ¬ P x) := by
  intro H
  apply Classical.byContradiction
  intro H1
  rewrite [not_exists_forall] at H1
  have Hexists := Classical.exists_true_of_nonempty Hne
  cases Hexists with
  | intro x _ =>
    have H2 := H1 x
    rewrite [Classical.not_forall] at H2
    cases H2 with
    | intro x1 H3 =>
      rewrite [Block_1.T5] at H3
      have Hq : Q x1 := And.left H3
      have Hqe : ∃ y, Q y := Exists.intro x1 Hq
      rewrite [<-@Classical.not_not (∃ y, Q y)] at Hqe
      have H3 := Block_1.modus_tollens H Hqe
      rewrite [Classical.not_forall] at H3
      cases H3 with
        | intro x2 Hnp =>
          have Hp : ¬ ¬ P x := And.right H3
          rewrite [Classical.not_not] at Hp
          have H4 := H1 x2
          rewrite [Classical.not_forall] at H4
          cases H4 with
          | intro x4 Hnimpl =>
            rewrite [Block_1.T5] at Hnimpl
            have Hp2 : ¬¬P x2 := And.right Hnimpl
            rewrite [Classical.not_not] at Hp2
            exact Hnp Hp2
```


To prove a forall, the forall introduction rule is just intro x, but you have to do that when you have the goal ∀ (x : α), P x.  So you can't use the assumptions x : α and Hp : P x to get ∀ (x : α), P x, unless that was the goal at the time you did intro x.  (This need to "declare" your forall lemma ahead of time might differ slightly from the logical presentation you are used to.)
At the point in the proof where you are trying to prove Hforall, you are no longer talking about all x : α, but a specific x.  So knowing that P x holds doesn't tell you anything about the other values of α (even if the steps in your proof hold for all x).
In your proof, you introduce x : α when you break up HExist into cases.  But note that x is not the variable you want to work with.  First, when you introduced it you didn't use intro x.  (It is a bit confusing, but your intro x _ => is not the intro tactic, but just invokes the automatic name of that case of HExist which happens to be called intro.) In short x isn't some arbitrary element of α, it is a specific x asserted to exist in HExist.  Second, even if you did use intro x, the goal at the time wasn't ∀ (x : α), P x so it wouldn't have helped.

In your proof, try moving your lemma Hforall to the outer part of the proof, say right after rewrite [not_exists_forall] at H1.
Then use intro x like follows:
  have Hforall : (∀ (x : α), P x) := by
    intro x
    sorry

This x is the variable you want to work with (and since it is in the outer part of the proof, you won't have other variables that could confuse you).  Then move in parts of your proof into the indented proof block to finish Hforall.

Some general advice for your exercise: (Edit: Although maybe in this case you did this.)  Try to first work this out with pen and paper, so you don't get lost in the details.  There is a clear main idea to the proof.  I can't tell from your Lean code if you grasp that main idea.  In order to prove ∃ x, ... you need to give a value of x.  What is that going to be?  (It might depend on various cases.  And yes, this proof will use classical logic.)

"Try to first work this out with pen and paper, so you don't get lost in the details." -
I did it, and wrote it as Lean code. I used the forall introduction on paper.
Can you give any hints? I tried to prove multiple times.

In Lean, forall introduction is just intro x.  But in your proof, the place you want to show ∀ (x : α), P x, it doesn’t hold.  (And I think your False goal isn’t provable.)  So your mistake must be further up.  (I didn’t look at your proof in detail.)

Also, can you make your example complete by providing Block_.T5?

@user4035 Ok, I better understand your issue. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

"Also, can you make your example complete by providing Block_.T5?" - added it.

@user4035, thanks.  I edited my answer once again.  I think this should be more clear now.

Is it possible to construct Hforall without sorry? Is this theorem provable with Lean? Maybe, I am missing something.

I solved it! Please, look at my answer.
